# Eclipse CDT MinGW path variables

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, eclipse-cdt, path-variables

My Eclipse didn't show any console outputs.
I tested the ".exe" in the debug file of my C++ project, with wich i received an error that "libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll" was missing.
I read abit on this and i found that i could simply copy/paste that file from my c:/MinGW/bin folder to the ".exe" in the "/debug" folder of my project.
That  helped me with that error but i then received the message that "libstdc++-6.dll" was missing, so i did the same again.

Now The ".exe" works fine and I get an output in my eclipse.

But now i'm afraid that i will get simillar erro's at my next build if i use some what more complex programming.
I also think that it would be very timeconsuming if i have to add those files too all of my future projects.

**Question:**
So my question now isn't there a way to tell eclpise that those .dll files are at "c:/MinGW/bin"?

**PS.**
I suspect that a similar question already exists but I wouldn't have a clue on what tags I'd have to search for.

Comment: Did you add "c:/MinGW/bin" to your Path environment variable or the installer automatically did it?

Comment: i wouln't have a clue on how to check this ? sorry :/

Comment: You can check it from command line (cmd.exe). Just type echo %PATH% and check if your mingw install (bin) directory is in the path. This makes things easier I think. If this cannot solve, then we gon with a different option.

Comment: Then, add it to your PATH. After that it should be okay. If you do not want to add it to your path (may be you would like to use multiple versions and etc.), it may be possible within Eclipse C/C++ settings (where you can append directories to your original PATH without modifying it). However, I prefer just adding MinGW bin/ to your PATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speacial thanks to @Deniz !

- right click on "my computer" => properties .
- on the right select "Advanced system settings".
- open "Enviormentvariables"
- search for "path"
- select Edit
- you'll have a list of paths, hit "end" on your keyboard to make sure you are at the end of this list.
- then add ";" to close the previous path and add the path to your MinGW/bin location. (by default C:\MinGW\bin).

result in adding ";C:\MinGW\bin"